# TV series nordic/arthurian/germanic late 80's w/ gore & nudes

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a TV series of the late 80's. Like nordic/arthurian/germanic miths. It must be European. It contained gore and nude scenes. I remember a man that was beheaded while standing and a lot of blood splashed from his neck to the air. Also remember nude readheads, nymph-like, on a river. I remember ice and snow. Please, tell me this is not a false memory.

Comment: Please, take a look at [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) about story identification tag, and [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Might be a false memory, but if it's not, honestly sounds like something older than the 80s.

Comment: Sounds like Game of Thrones but obviously that's not 80s

Answer (score 4):

There is a finnish TV series from the 80's called "The Iron Age" (Rauta Aika). It's inspired by the finnish national saga "Kalevala" and may be what you're looking for.

[image]

From its [DVD-set information](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/361296202335):

> Four-part TV-movie "Rauta-Aika" is based on Kalevala, but with lot's of changes. Kaleva is Finland's national epic, whichs ancient poetry is filled with spells, incantations, myths and heroic lore. Making of this film costed at least two milloin euros, calling to some sources maybe even more. The movie can seem often very artistic for people that are used to watch Hollywood and USA productions, but every detail in "Rauta-Aika" has it's purpose. Artistic style also makes this movie mysterious and the ambience of beeing at "ancient north" grows very strong.

It depicts some nudity and deaths, and [according to IMDB's keywords there is a decapitation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0190919/keywords?ref_=tt_stry_kw). This is a link to a short Youtube clip where you can see a brief glimpse of naked children, but as usual with Youtube it contains no (explicit) sex nor violence.

Comment: The [IMBD page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0190919/) has "head cut off" as one of its keywords.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks a lot. I'll add those facts from IMDB to my answer. With those "full frontal nudity" and "head cut off" keywords it totally looks like the correct answer.